# Pandas csv_read function

Tags: pandas

Hello i'm new to Python and i am trying to load a csv file into google colab.
Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("E:\Scuola AI\Machine learning I\Machine learning\File\Classified Data")
```

This code gives me the following error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:\\Scuola AI\\Machine learning I\\Machine learning\\File\\Classified Data'
```

Comment: You have first to upload your CSV file onto Google Colab, as it cannot read files in the disk of your computer.